# Pose Estimation Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: react-native, tensorflow.js

I am having a problem getting tensorflow working with react native. I keep getting:

Maximum call stack size exceeded

These are my tensorflow dependancies:

```
        "@tensorflow-models/blazeface": "^0.0.7",
        "@tensorflow-models/handpose": "^0.0.7",
        "@tensorflow-models/mobilenet": "^2.0.4",
        "@tensorflow-models/posenet": "^2.2.2",
        "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^2.7.0",
        "@tensorflow/tfjs-automl": "^1.0.0",
        "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^2.7.0",
        "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.5.0",
```

I have been trying a lot of different examples and code to try and find the problem, but this is the code i am currently trying to run:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
  StatusBar,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
// import { fetch } from "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";
// import * as mobilenet from "@tensorflow-models/mobilenet";
import * as handpose from "@tensorflow-models/handpose";
// import * as jpeg from "jpeg-js";
// import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
// import Constants from "expo-constants";
// import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
// import { ExpoWebGLRenderingContext } from "expo-gl";
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import { cameraWithTensors } from "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";

export function Liveness() {
  const [isTfReady, setIsTfReady] = useState(false);
  const [isModelReady, setIsModelReady] = useState(false);
  const [model, setModel] = useState(null);
  const [predictions, setPredictions] = useState(false);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(false);
  const [cameraType, setCameraType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.front);

  const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function go() {
      console.log("run");
      await tf.ready();
      setIsTfReady(true);
      const model = await handpose.load();
      setIsModelReady(true);
      setModel(model);
      //   console.log("predictions:", predictions);
      //   setPredictions(predictions);
    }
    go();
  }, []);

  function HandleImageTensorReady(images) {
    const loop = async () => {
      const nextImageTensor = images.next().value;
      console.log("nextImageTensor:", nextImageTensor);

      //
      // do something with tensor here
      //

      if (nextImageTensor) {
        console.log("yes go");
        const predictions = await model.estimateHands(nextImageTensor);
        console.log("predictions:", predictions);
      }

    };
    loop();
  }

  const inputTensorWidth = 152;
  const inputTensorHeight = 200;
  const AUTORENDER = true;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
      <Text style={styles.transparentText}>Tap to choose image go</Text>
      <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          TFJS ready? {isTfReady ? <Text>✅</Text> : <Text />}
        </Text>

        <View style={styles.loadingModelContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Model ready? </Text>
          {isModelReady
            ? <Text style={styles.text}>✅</Text>
            : <ActivityIndicator size="small" />}
        </View>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.imageWrapper}
      >
        <TensorCamera
          // Standard Camera props
          style={styles.camera}
          type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
          zoom={0}
          // tensor related props
          cameraTextureHeight={1200}
          cameraTextureWidth={1600}
          resizeHeight={inputTensorHeight}
          resizeWidth={inputTensorWidth}
          resizeDepth={3}
          onReady={(images, updatePreview, gl) =>
            HandleImageTensorReady(images)}
          autorender={AUTORENDER}
        />
        {/* <Text style={styles.transparentText}>Tap to choose image</Text> */}
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.predictionWrapper} />
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <Text style={styles.poweredBy}>Powered by:</Text>
        {/* <Image source={require("./assets/tfjs.jpg")} style={styles.tfLogo} /> */}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#171f24",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  loadingContainer: {
    marginTop: 80,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  text: {
    color: "#ffffff",
    fontSize: 16
  },
  cameraContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  },
  camera: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 50,
    top: 100,
    width: 600 / 2,
    height: 800 / 2,
    zIndex: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "black",
    borderRadius: 0
  },
  loadingModelContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: 10
  },
  imageWrapper: {
    width: 280,
    height: 280,
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: "#cf667f",
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderStyle: "dashed",
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 10,
    position: "relative",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  imageContainer: {
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    bottom: 10,
    right: 10
  },
  predictionWrapper: {
    height: 100,
    width: "100%",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  transparentText: {
    color: "#ffffff",
    opacity: 0.7
  },
  footer: {
    marginTop: 40
  },
  poweredBy: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#e69e34",
    marginBottom: 6
  },
  tfLogo: {
    width: 125,
    height: 70
  }
});
```

If anyone has any tips or suggestions it would be a big help as i have been looking at this for days and need some help.

Comment: Does my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is that you are not disposing of the tensors after using them for making predictions which causes them to build up on the device and throw the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. You just need to add `tf.dispose(model)` after making the prediction on the tensor with the model. You should also use `tf.disposeVariables()` which disposes of all variables kept in the backend engine.

```
  function HandleImageTensorReady(images) {
    const loop = async () => {
      const nextImageTensor = images.next().value;
      console.log("nextImageTensor:", nextImageTensor);

      if (nextImageTensor) {
        console.log("yes go");
        const predictions = await model.estimateHands(nextImageTensor);
        console.log("predictions:", predictions);
      }
      tf.dispose(model);
      tf.disposeVariables() 
    };
    loop();
  }
```

### Edit:

After spending more time reading through the code I found an issue with `TensorCamera` where you pass in a property `zoom` instead [it does not have this property](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_react_native/0.5.0/#cameraWithTensors) so remove it:

```
<TensorCamera
  // Standard Camera props
  style={styles.camera}
  type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
  // tensor related props
  cameraTextureHeight={1200}
  cameraTextureWidth={1600}
  resizeHeight={inputTensorHeight}
  resizeWidth={inputTensorWidth}
  resizeDepth={3}
  onReady={(images, updatePreview, gl) =>
    HandleImageTensorReady(images)
  }
  autorender={AUTORENDER}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still the same problem. It is something to do with:  const predictions = await model.estimateHands(nextImageTensor); If i comment everything else out i don't get the error.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow-models/handpose does show it being estimateHands, and i looked inside the module and it does exist, so i am still a bit lost.

Comment: @Cannonball2134 apologies that was my mistake but I found another issue with the code. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: thanks for your help, due to the problems i was having i had to put the project on hold. If you can think of anything else that might be causing the problem please let me know.

Comment: Can you confirm the updated answer does not work?

Comment: I will definitely check it, but i barely have time to breathe at the moment, so it might be a while, but really appreciate the help.